# How to update k8s certificates safely and completely？

Tags: kubernetes, certificate

How to update k8s certificate:

Some certificates in the k8s cluster are currently expired, prompting:

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is
>   not yet valid. Take a look at the online cluster master.

The `ca.crt` and `front-proxy-ca.crt` are not expired, but the `front-proxy-client.crt`, `apiserver-kubelet-client.crt`, and `apiserver.crt` are expired.

So manually passing the existing `ca.key` generates the `apiserver.crt` on the master[Refer to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885636/kubernetes-expired-certificate). However, new errors occurred, suggesting:

> the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

What is the way to update the certificate of k8s cluster?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The latest kubeadm should have support for [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/67910).

Expected commands:

```
renew all
renew apiserver
renew apiserver-kubelet-client
renew apiserver-etcd-client
renew front-proxy-client
renew etcd-server
renew etcd-peer
renew etcd-healthcheck-client
```

You generally have to review all the certs above, you can also renew them manually using [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) or [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl) and using the CA in `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.pem`

Comment: Can I install the latest kubeadm version on the k8s cluster of 1.7.2?

Comment: I would really start with a new cluster. There's guide to upgrade an existing kubeadm cluster from 1.7.x to 1.8.x [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-8/)  but that assumes that you setup your 1.7.2  cluster using kubeadm