# Renewing Kubernetes cluster certificates

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, kubelet

We currently having 2 Master 2 Worker node cluster on **Kubernetes v1.13.4**.The cluster is down as the kubelet certificate located in `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt` has expired and the kubelet service is not running. On checking the kubelet logs I get the following error

> E0808 09:49:35.126533   55154 bootstrap.go:209] Part of the existing bootstrap client certificate is expired: 2019-08-06 22:39:23 +0000 UTC

The following certificates `ca.crt`, `apiserver-kubelet-client.crt` are valid. We are unable to renew the `kubelet.crt` certificate manually by using the **kubeadm-config.yaml**. Can someone please provide the steps to renew the certificate.

We have tried setting  `--rotate-certificates` property and also using **kubeadm-config.yaml** but since we are using **v1.13.4** `kubeadm --config` flag is **not present**.

On checking the kubelet logs I get the following error

> E0808 09:49:35.126533   55154 bootstrap.go:209] Part of the existing bootstrap client certificate is expired: 2019-08-06 22:39:23 +0000 UTC

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that only `kubelet.crt` has expired and `apiserver-kubelet-client.crt` is valid, you can try to renew it by command `kubeadm alpha certs renew` based on [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#manual-certificate-renewal).

Second way to renew kubeadm certificates is upgrade version like in [this article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-14/).

You can also try by using `kubeadm init phase certs all`. It was explained in [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320930/renew-kubernetes-pki-after-expired) case.

Let me know if that helped. If not provide more information with more logs.