# Failed to create SubnetManager: asn1: structure error: tags don't match

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, flannel, flanneld

While this error message is just a symptom, my problem is real.

My bare-metal cluster experienced a certificate expired situation. i managed to renew all certificates, but upon restart, most pods wouldn't work. the pod that seems responsible, is the flannel one (crashloopbackoff).

logs for the flannel pods show

```
I1120 22:24:00.541277       1 main.go:475] Determining IP address of default interface
I1120 22:24:00.541546       1 main.go:488] Using interface with name eth0 and address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
I1120 22:24:00.541565       1 main.go:505] Defaulting external address to interface address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
E1120 22:24:03.572745       1 main.go:232] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-dmrzh': Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-dmrzh: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: getsockopt: network is unreachable
```

on the host there is not even a flannel interface anymore. neither a systemd file

running flanneld manually yields this output

```
I1120 20:12:15.923966   26361 main.go:446] Determining IP address of default interface
I1120 20:12:15.924171   26361 main.go:459] Using interface with name eth0 and address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
I1120 20:12:15.924187   26361 main.go:476] Defaulting external address to interface address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
E1120 20:12:15.924285   26361 main.go:223] Failed to create SubnetManager: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:2 length:1 isCompound:false}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} tbsCertificate @2
```

the available pieces of evidence point in several directions, but upon checking those out, it points somewehre else. so i need a pointer to which part causes the problem.

- is it etcd?
- is it the new etcd certificate?
- is it the missing flannel-interface?
- is it the non-operational flanneld?
- is it something not listed here?

if there is information missing here, please ask, i can surely provide.

key specs:
- host: ubuntu 18.04
- kubeadm 1.13.2

thank you and best regards,
scones

UPDATE1

```
$ k get cs,po,svc
NAME                                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
componentstatus/controller-manager   Healthy   ok                   
componentstatus/scheduler            Healthy   ok                   
componentstatus/etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}   

NAME                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cert-manager-6dc5c68468-hkb6j             0/1     Error              51         89d
pod/coredns-86c58d9df4-dtdxq                  0/1     Completed          23         304d
pod/coredns-86c58d9df4-k7h7m                  0/1     Completed          23         304d
pod/etcd-redacted                             1/1     Running            2506       304d
pod/hostpath-provisioner-5c6754fbd4-ckvnp     0/1     Error              12         222d
pod/kube-apiserver-redacted                   1/1     Running            1907       304d
pod/kube-controller-manager-redacted          1/1     Running            2682       304d
pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-dmrzh               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   338        372d
pod/kube-proxy-q8jgs                          1/1     Running            15         304d
pod/kube-scheduler-redacted                   1/1     Running            2694       304d
pod/metrics-metrics-server-65cd865c9f-dbh85   0/1     Error              2658       120d
pod/tiller-deploy-865b88d89-8ftzs             0/1     Error              170        305d

NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns                 ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   372d
service/metrics-metrics-server   ClusterIP   10.97.186.19     <none>        443/TCP         120d
service/tiller-deploy            ClusterIP   10.103.184.226   <none>        44134/TCP       354d
```

unfortunately i don't recall how i installed flannel a year ago.
kubectl version is also 1.13.2, as is the cluster

the linked post by @hanx is about renewing certificated, not broken network overlays, so not applicable.

Comment: Please provide information about currently running or crashed cluster components how did you deploy flannel overlay network (version, link) `kubectl get cs, kubectl get pos,svc -n kube-system, kubectl version`.
Please take a look for this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320930/renew-kubernetes-pki-after-expired/56334732#56334732). Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Please take a look at [Older versions of Kubernetes Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/443d773037ac0f3b8a996a6de018b903b6a58c62/Documentation/kubernetes.md#older-versions-of-kubernetes) and try to recreate overlay network

Comment: @Hanx this does not change the outcome. the flannel pod still won't start. same error.

Comment: I have tried to recreate this issue without results using v.1.14. Current Linux kernel for [Ubuntu 18.04](https://lwn.net/Articles/802858/), now gcp ships 18.04 with a v5.0 based Linux kernel. v1.13.2 will fail (due to kernel and kubernetes-cni v0.6.0) incompatibility. Please provide more information what you did (commands) how certs were recreated. Please use systemctl status kubelet, journalctl -u kubelet, kubectl cluster-info dump, describe, logs for the rest of the pods like coredns, etcd. This error "Failed to create SubnetManager: asn1: structure error" it can be improper cert structure.