# Kubernetes: failure loading apiserver-etcd-client certificate: the certificate has expired

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

I am unable to run any `kubectl` commands and I believe it is a result of an expired apiserver-etcd-client certificate.

```
$ openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt -noout -text |grep ' Not '
            Not Before: Jun 25 17:28:17 2018 GMT
            Not After : Jun 25 17:28:18 2019 GMT
```

The log from the failed apiserver container shows:

```
Unable to create storage backend: config (&{ /registry [https://127.0.0.1:2379] /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt true false 1000 0xc420363900 <nil> 5m0s 1m0s}), err (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: getsockopt: connection refused)
```

I am using kubeadm 1.10, and would like to upgrade to 1.14.  I was able to renew several expired certificates described by [issue 581](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/581) on GitHub.  Following the instructions updated the following keys & certs in `/etc/kubernetes/pki`:

```
apiserver
apiserver-kubelet-client
front-proxy-client
```

Next, I tried:

```
kubeadm --config kubeadm.yaml alpha phase certs apiserver-etcd-client
```

Where the `kubeadm.yaml` file is:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: MasterConfiguration
api:
  advertiseAddress: 172.XX.XX.XXX
kubernetesVersion: v1.10.5
```

But it returns:

```
failure loading apiserver-etcd-client certificate: the certificate has expired
```

Further, in the directory `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd` with the exception of the `ca` cert and key, all of the remaining certificates and keys are expired.

Is there a way to renew the expired certs without resorting to rebuilding the cluster?

```
Logs from the etcd container:
$ sudo docker logs e4da061fc18f
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705743 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.1.12
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705798 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: 918698add
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705803 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.8.7
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705809 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705816 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 2, total number of available CPUs is 2
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705848 N | etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705871 I | embed: peerTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key, ca = , trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-cert-auth = true
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705878 W | embed: The scheme of peer url http://localhost:2380 is HTTP while peer key/cert files are presented. Ignored peer key/cert files.
2019-07-02 20:46:45.705882 W | embed: The scheme of peer url http://localhost:2380 is HTTP while client cert auth (--peer-client-cert-auth) is enabled. Ignored client cert auth for this url.
2019-07-02 20:46:45.712218 I | embed: listening for peers on http://localhost:2380
2019-07-02 20:46:45.712267 I | embed: listening for client requests on 127.0.0.1:2379
2019-07-02 20:46:45.716737 I | warning: ignoring ServerName for user-provided CA for backwards compatibility is deprecated
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718103 I | etcdserver: recovered store from snapshot at index 13621371
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718116 I | etcdserver: name = default
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718121 I | etcdserver: data dir = /var/lib/etcd
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718126 I | etcdserver: member dir = /var/lib/etcd/member
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718130 I | etcdserver: heartbeat = 100ms
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718133 I | etcdserver: election = 1000ms
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718136 I | etcdserver: snapshot count = 10000
2019-07-02 20:46:45.718144 I | etcdserver: advertise client URLs = https://127.0.0.1:2379
2019-07-02 20:46:45.842281 I | etcdserver: restarting member 8e9e05c52164694d in cluster cdf818194e3a8c32 at commit index 13629377
2019-07-02 20:46:45.842917 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d became follower at term 1601
2019-07-02 20:46:45.842940 I | raft: newRaft 8e9e05c52164694d [peers: [8e9e05c52164694d], term: 1601, commit: 13629377, applied: 13621371, lastindex: 13629377, lastterm: 1601]
2019-07-02 20:46:45.843071 I | etcdserver/api: enabled capabilities for version 3.1
2019-07-02 20:46:45.843086 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 8e9e05c52164694d [http://localhost:2380] to cluster cdf818194e3a8c32 from store
2019-07-02 20:46:45.843093 I | etcdserver/membership: set the cluster version to 3.1 from store
2019-07-02 20:46:45.846312 I | mvcc: restore compact to 13274147
2019-07-02 20:46:45.854822 I | warning: ignoring ServerName for user-provided CA for backwards compatibility is deprecated
2019-07-02 20:46:45.855232 I | warning: ignoring ServerName for user-provided CA for backwards compatibility is deprecated
2019-07-02 20:46:45.855267 I | etcdserver: starting server... [version: 3.1.12, cluster version: 3.1]
2019-07-02 20:46:45.855293 I | embed: ClientTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key, ca = , trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-cert-auth = true
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443331 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d is starting a new election at term 1601
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443388 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d became candidate at term 1602
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443405 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d received MsgVoteResp from 8e9e05c52164694d at term 1602
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443419 I | raft: 8e9e05c52164694d became leader at term 1602
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443428 I | raft: raft.node: 8e9e05c52164694d elected leader 8e9e05c52164694d at term 1602
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443699 I | etcdserver: published {Name:default ClientURLs:[https://127.0.0.1:2379]} to cluster cdf818194e3a8c32
2019-07-02 20:46:46.443768 I | embed: ready to serve client requests
2019-07-02 20:46:46.444012 I | embed: serving client requests on 127.0.0.1:2379
2019-07-02 20:48:05.528061 N | pkg/osutil: received terminated signal, shutting down...
2019-07-02 20:48:05.528103 I | etcdserver: skipped leadership transfer for single member cluster
```

systemd start-up script:

```
sudo systemctl status -l kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-07-01 14:54:24 UTC; 1 day 23h ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 9422 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 13
   Memory: 47.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─9422 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --authentication-token-webhook=true --authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --rotate-certificates=true --cert-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/pki

Jul 03 14:10:49 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:49.871276    9422 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 03 14:10:49 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:49.872444    9422 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:461: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 03 14:10:49 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:49.880422    9422 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:452: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 03 14:10:50 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:50.871913    9422 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 03 14:10:50 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:50.872948    9422 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:461: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 03 14:10:50 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:50.880792    9422 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:452: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
Jul 03 14:10:50 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: I0703 14:10:50.964989    9422 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jul 03 14:10:50 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: I0703 14:10:50.966644    9422 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com
Jul 03 14:10:50 ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com kubelet[9422]: E0703 14:10:50.967012    9422 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "ahub-k8s-m1.aws-intanalytic.com" with API server: Post https://172.31.22.241:6443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 172.31.22.241:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Comment: can you post logs of the etcd container? I know you probably can't do `kubectl` therefore do `docker logs ETCD_CONTAINER_ID`. The reason I ask this is because  your error says "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: getsockopt: connection refused)" Just need to see if etcd is running healthy

Comment: updated post to include the log from the etcd container.

Answer (score 2):

Background: kubectl utilizes a file called `config` (location in CentOS: /$USER/.kube/config) to identify itself (user which is you) to the api-server. This file is a copy of the `admin.conf` (location in CentOS: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf .

Now Upgrade from 1.10 to 1.14 and renewing existing certs in an already expired cert cluster, should be treated different just not to complicate the process!

FYI you should upgrade one hop at a time which 1.10 to 1.11 to 1.12 ..... check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-14/) page avaiable for different version. Also VERY important to check the [changelogs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and perform the *mandatories* before upgrading from one hop to next.

Coming back to RENEWing certs `kubeadm --config kubeadm.yaml alpha phase certs apiserver-etcd-client` alone is not enough, Please perform `kubeadm --config kubeadm.yaml alpha phase certs all`
Note following the above you need to perform `kubeadm --config kubeadm.yaml alpha phase kubeconfig all` in all nodes as the ca.crt has changed by now. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49885636/4451944)

In future you might want to consider [cert rotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/certificate-rotation/)

Comment: Thank you, @garlicFrancium.  I have edited the post to illustrate how cert rotation was in effect, which is why this was an unusual situation.  I ended up rebuilding anyway since it was the practical means to upgrade from 1.10 to 1.15.

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes 1.14 and above, you can just run `sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew all` and reboot the master. For older versions the manual steps are:

```sh
sudo -sE #switch to root

# Check certs on master to see expiration dates
echo -n /etc/kubernetes/pki/{apiserver,apiserver-kubelet-client,apiserver-etcd-client,front-proxy-client,etcd/healthcheck-client,etcd/peer,etcd/server}.crt | xargs -d ' ' -I {} bash -c "ls -hal {} && openssl x509 -in {} -noout -enddate"


# Move existing keys/config files so they can be recreated
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key{,.old}
 
mv /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf{,.old}
mv /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf{,.old}
 
# Regenerate keys and config files
kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm.yaml
kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver-etcd-client --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm.yaml
kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver-kubelet-client
kubeadm alpha phase certs front-proxy-client
kubeadm alpha phase certs etcd-healthcheck-client
kubeadm alpha phase certs etcd-peer
kubeadm alpha phase certs etcd-server
 
kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm.yaml
# then need to restart the kubelet and services, but for the master probably best to just reboot
```