# Kubernetes dashboard renew SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

At the moment my kubernetes dashboard shows me that my session in insecure. I have updated the path at with I keep the dashboard certs (/root/certs/) and I need to know how to get kubernetes to use them.

I have tried to:

- Delete the secret `kubernetes-dashboard-certs` which deletes that secret successfully.
- Add my new dashboard.crt & dashboard.key to /root/certs/ (readable by all)
- Created the secret again with `kubectl create secret generic kubernetes-dashboard-certs --from-file=/root/certs -n kubernetes`
- Logged into dashboard and it still shows insecure (because the SSL cert is not being updated)

Comment: let know community about usefulness of answer and upvote/accept answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you created authentication token (RBAC)? You can get more information from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md).

Try to regenerate your cluster certificates, check [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#renew-certificates-with-the-certificates-api). If you used kubeadm then from control plane node you can run:

```
$ kubeadm alpha certs renew
```

Also what can be helpful is to restart apiserver:

```
user@test-calico:~$ sudo docker ps -a | grep apiserver
834ed10cbce3        5eb2d3fc7a44                   "kube-apiserver --ad…"   4 weeks ago         Up 4 weeks                                      k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-test-calico_kube-system_019eaca18f2defc3759027d8220b3451_0
87c22315ce21        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1           "/pause"                 4 weeks ago         Up 4 weeks                                      k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-test-calico_kube-system_019eaca18f2defc3759027d8220b3451_0

$ sudo docker restart 834ed10cbce3
```

Please refer to following post
[Kubernetes: expired certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885636/kubernetes-expired-certificate).